# Merge Replication and varbinary(max)

Tags: c#, .net, sql, t-sql, merge-replication

I have an issue with an existing application that uses merge replication. The replication sends varbinary(max) data (images) and usually not a problem as the usually only a handful of images will be send at once via the subscriber.

However, the problem is a user is trying to send lots (dozens) and this of course is hitting a limit. The response being logged is:

> The Merge Agent received the following error status and message from
>   the Internet Information Services (IIS) server during Web
>   synchronization: [404 :'Not Found']. When troubleshooting, ensure that
>   the Web synchronization settings for the subscription are correct, and
>   increase the internet timeout setting at the Subscriber and the
>   connection timeout at the Web server.

This is defiantly not a timeout caused by a time span as I am able to reproduce this in my development environment over the network, and is most defiantly a data/size issue.

I have checked @stream_blob_columns is set to true for the article in question.
I have checked 'max text repl size' is set to -1 (no limit) for the SQL Server (though I think this is not used for merge replication).

Have I missed anything else? I would much rather increase a setting and educate the user to 'synchronize' more often than rework the way these images are replicated back to the central database/web server.

Comment: There are limitations with replicating large volumes of data using Web Synchronization.  You might be hitting this limit.  Have a look at the section Replicating Large Volumes of Data in Configure Web Synchronization (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151255.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Brandon, I have read through this and forgot to mention we have already tried to change the WebSyncMaxXmlSize  in the registry. I agree limitations are probably reached and we are looking at removing the images from blobs and using FTP to synchronize these between offline and online applications. Thanks